# Laravel router namespace method

Tags: laravel

In Laravel documentation [routing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing) there is a namespace method.

```
Route::namespace
```

I tried to explore what does it really do but couldn't find it's definition in Laravel source codes. Where is it?

Comment: This is the namespace that will dictate where the controllers for your route(s) are loaded from

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not related to code, just to group the routes. Like this:

The source is here: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/b73691ac7b309cd2c4fb29b32d3eed76fecca58b/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteGroup.php#L40, it just adds the namespace at end of the current namespace.

You have a controller group like 'Products' for example,

```
App/
    Http/
        Controllers/
            Products/
                Stocks.php 
                Prices.php
                Sizes.php
```

And you need to modify their namespaces like this to meet the PSR-4 requirements to enable autoloading of controllers:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Products;            

class Stocks {
      function index(){

      }
}
```

Then if you want to access the methods of these controllers, you might want to group them with `Route::namespace()`:

```
Route::namespace("Products")->group(function(){
    Route::get("stocks", "Stocks@index");
});
```

This will search for the `Stocks` class in the `App\Http\Controllers\Products` namespace instead of `App\Http\Controllers` namespace. and call the `index` method.

**Note** that you might run `composer dumpautoload` to let the framework rebuild the autoload.php with the PSR-4 namespaces to make these things effective.

---

**Later Edit:**

`framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php` defines the `Route` class, which redirects the `Route::namespace` method to `RouterRegistrar` class at this line:

```
/**
 * Dynamically handle calls into the router instance.
 *
 * @param  string  $method
 * @param  array  $parameters
 * @return mixed
 */
public function __call($method, $parameters)
{
    if (static::hasMacro($method)) {
        return $this->macroCall($method, $parameters);
    }
    if ($method == 'middleware') {
        return (new RouteRegistrar($this))->attribute($method, is_array($parameters[0]) ? $parameters[0] : $parameters);
    }
    return (new RouteRegistrar($this))->attribute($method, $parameters[0]);
}
```

in the last line. And in that method,

```
/**
 * The attributes that can be set through this class.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $allowedAttributes = [
    'as', 'domain', 'middleware', 'name', 'namespace', 'prefix',
];

/**
 * Set the value for a given attribute.
 *
 * @param  string  $key
 * @param  mixed  $value
 * @return $this
 *
 * @throws \InvalidArgumentException
 */
public function attribute($key, $value)
{
    if (! in_array($key, $this->allowedAttributes)) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException("Attribute [{$key}] does not exist.");
    }
    $this->attributes[Arr::get($this->aliases, $key, $key)] = $value;
    return $this;
}
```

`namespace` attribute is being set, to use in `->group()` method.

Comment: I guess he is concerned about the fact that you cannot find the function "namespace", but "formatNamespace"

Comment: But there is not the "namespace" method referenced in the documentation. Is there an alias? A redirection? What is the mechanism? Is the documentation wrong?

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/b73691ac7b309cd2c4fb29b32d3eed76fecca58b/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php#L1208

Comment: This line handles the unexisting methods and these are registered as macros instead of direct methods. I'll find and share the macro.

Comment: I added the path which `namespace` attribute is set and used.

Comment: Thank you very much! You have my gratitude (and my upvote). What a convoluted way to call a function, by the way. It's a debugging nightmare.